# Disable wordpress update notification

Tags: functions

i need a code to paste in my wordpress theme function for disable wordpress update notification.

https://prnt.sc/tyigt3

Comment: You can put a look just there: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/hide-the-wordpress-update-notification/

Answer (score 0):

found the solution!

```
remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
```